# Why using log transformation of target variable helps regression return positive values?

Tags: regression, logarithm

I am working on a linear regression model predicting the quantity of goods to order in the future. However, with some items, the model return negative values (despite the fact that all target values for the training set are positive). To solve this problem, I've used log transformation with the target variable (in this case = no. of goods to order) and the model return all positive values.

Could you please explain how using log help the model return all positive values? I would really love to understand the mathematic behind it. Thank you so much for your answer.

/// update ///

*I've found the answer to my own question from this amazing blog post!
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/log-transform-for-positivity-d3e1f183c804*

*Please correct me if I am wrong, my understanding is that negative values (which should not be there) are from the effort of the model to find the smallest error for the whole dataset. Since the data set has a large range of values and sometimes with outliers, decreasing the error of high value data points (on the expense of low value data points) result in less error for the whole model. Log transformation of target variable help lessens the distance between these data points and result in the better model.*

Comment: The *sole* reason is that logarithms apply only to positive numbers, so any model that estimates logarithms perforce is estimating positive values.